# Trying to understand per app language preferences in Android 13

Tags: android, android-13

My app supports 8 languages, `English`, `French`, `German`, `Arabic`, `Spanish`, `Mandarin Chinese`, `Japanese` and `Russian` languages.

There is a language picker inside `SettingsFragment` that allows the user to change the app language.

Users who have Android 13 and higher can change the app language as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features/app-languages#how-user).

In Android 13 and higher, Should I remove the language picker from `SettingsFragment`? Because the user can change the app language from outside as I mentioned in the link above.

I did not understand all points of this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features/app-languages) so maybe my question was already answered there.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand it, you can remove it, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create locales_config.xml and add your language list inside it like [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#use-localeconfig)

After user pick language in your setting just call instead of keep value in database or share

```
val appLocale: LocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("xx-YY")
// Call this on the main thread as it may require Activity.restart()
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
```

In my opinion you can keep the language picker for facilitate user.

Comment: The developer notes recommend not implementing the locales_config.xml approach and instead recommend enabling automatic per-app language support: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#use-localeconfig